# Livewire @entangle issue with mutliple post

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm actually using a component I made using Livewire and AlpineJS.
The issue I got is the following :
I have a button to add a new section, in this section I can wrote title and description (wysiwyg editor) so to handle this I have in my component :

```
<div
    x-data="{content: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')),...setupEditor()}"
    x-init="() => init($refs.editor)"
    wire:ignore
    {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}>
```

And in my livewire php file :

```
protected $rules = [
    'newLesson.*.title' => 'required|string',
    'newLesson.*.lesson_content' => 'required|string',
    'newLesson.*.type_content' => 'required|string',
];
```

So in my livewire blade I have something like this :

```
<x-editor wire:model.lazy="newLesson.{{$i}}.lesson_content"></x-editor>
```

But when I try, I've got an error in my console :

> SupportAlpine.js:102 Livewire Entangle Error: Livewire property
> 'newLesson.4.lesson_content' cannot be found

Did some of you already got this kind of issue ?
I don't really know how to handle it actually.
Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: What is the value of the `newLesson` property? Are you sure it is not null? Is it array? What is the count of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Worked through the issue on Livewire discord and solved it

For anyone else coming across it, the addLesson method was referencing $newLessons instead of $newLesson.